# Como evitar el registro de usuarios duplicados en Python y MYSQL

Tags: mysql, python

he estado aprendiendo por ejemplos y videos Python y vi como hacer un formulario de registros pero lo que no he aprendido es **como evitar el duplicado de usuarios y correos electrónicos en Python con Mysql** en mi ejemplo, dejo el código con divisiones para ver si me pueden ayudar a saber que es lo que necesito hacer, agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

```
""" ===LIBRERIAS IMPORTADAS=== """

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
import mysql.connector
import os


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

""" ===HOST=== """

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="remotemysql.com", user="imAlV4Be1J", password="C4B1wE9DxE", database="imAlV4Be1J")
cursor = conn.cursor()


""" ===DIRECTORIOS=== """

@app.route('/')
def signin_signup():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    if 'user_id' in session:

        return render_template('dashboard.html')
    else:
        return redirect('/')



""" ===PARAMETROS DE FORMULARIO DE REGISTRO=== """

@app.route('/add_user', methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
    name = request.form.get('un-fullname')
    user = request.form.get('un-user')
    email = request.form.get('un-email')
    password = request.form.get('un-password')

    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`,`fullname`,`user`,`email`,`password`)VALUES
    (NULL,'{}','{}','{}','{}')""".format(name, user, email, password))
    conn.commit()

    cursor.execute(
        """SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` LIKE '{}' AND `email` LIKE '{}'""".format(user, email))
    myuser = cursor.fetchall()
    session['user_id'] = myuser[0][0]
    return redirect('/dashboard')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=2000)
```

Comment: Las opciones son variadas, establecer un índice `unique` en la declaración de la columna `email` y  `usuario` o hacer un *conteo* de los registros por medio de un `SELECT` que coincidan y en función de ello construir una lógica que 2 saldias notificar o insertar según sea el caso, considera intentar algo y mejorar tu pregunta en dudas mas específicas

Comment: gracias amigo por ayudarme, crees poder adjuntar algún enlace que me ayude con mas documentación de como hacerlo con Python y Mysql? solo he encontrado como hacerlo de Mysql con PHP

Comment: Lo mas fácil es con puro mysql, busca en su documentación sobre el index `unique`

Comment: Aunque podrías sentirte tentado a bajarte todos los email de la base de datos y confrontarlos con el nuevo email, es más eficiente hacer trabajar el motor de la base de datos, podrías incluso verificar si el email existe haciendo una query.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear bien la base de datos con datos unicos, sean estos llaves primarias, indices, unicos, etc. Luego desde python cuando registres a un usuario nuevo, revisas si esa llave existe o no, y creas la validacion antes de la creacion.

En resumidas cuentas tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

- Base de datos:

```
Tabla: usuarios
Llave primaria ID - email único
```

- Python:

```
Creación del Usuario
|-> El usuario ingresa sus datos (nombre, correo, password, etc)
|-> Creas una secuencia que busque datos únicos (correo, id, etc) y si el correo ya existe, no se puede crear
|-> Si los datos únicos no existen, puedes crear el usuario
|-> Agregas validaciones y demases para que el usuario no ingrese datos erróneos
```